Unable to compile TypeScript:error TS2339:Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>
I getting annoyed about typescript in my node api. I have written a auth.ts At first typescript has not accepted the req.user.
// error messages
01:01:07 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
middleware/auth.ts(34,9): error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
enter image description here
// @types/custom.d.ts
import { Request } from "express";
import { IUser } from "../models/user.model";

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request{
            user?: IUser;
        }
    }
}

// middleware/auth.ts

import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { CatchAsyncError } from "./catchAsyncError";
import ErrorHandler from "../utils/ErrorHandler";
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { redis } from "../utils/redis"; 

// authenticated User
export const isAutheticated = CatchAsyncError(
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const access_token = req.cookies.access_token;
    console.log(access_token);

    if (!access_token) {
      return next(
        new ErrorHandler("Please login to access this resources", 400)
      );
    }

    const decodeed = jwt.verify(
      access_token,
      process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN as string
    ) as JwtPayload;

    if (!decodeed) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Access token is not valid ", 400));
    }

    const user = await redis.get(decodeed.id);

    if (!user) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found", 400));
    }

    req.user = JSON.parse(user) ;
    next();
  }
);
```

